# Swift: Add images to ScrollView

Tags: swift, uiimage, scrollview

Currently I have colors for the buttons in my ScrollView, but I'd like the buttons to have images instead of them just being colored. So, I'd like to completely get rid of the colors that I currently have in my code and replace them with images. Here is my code:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var categoryScrollView: UIScrollView!


    var categoryArr = ["Button1","Button2","Button3","Button4","Button5", "Button 6", "Button 7", "Button 8", "Button 9", "Button 10", "Button 11", "Button 12"]
    var buttonColors = [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.magentaColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.magentaColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.brownColor()]

//var buttonColors = [String?]()
    let kPadding:CGFloat = 20


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        let buttonSize = CGSizeMake(categoryScrollView.bounds.size.width/2, categoryScrollView.bounds.size.height/2)//hal

        let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(buttonSize, buttonCount: 12)
        categoryScrollView.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size
        categoryScrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)
        categoryScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        categoryScrollView.delegate = self
        categoryScrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        categoryScrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default
        categoryScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    }


    func colorButtonsView(buttonSize:CGSize, buttonCount:Int) -> UIView {

        //let images: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "image1.png")!, UIImage(named: "image2.png")!]


        let buttonView = UIView()
        buttonView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(50,142)
        let padding = CGSizeMake(kPadding, kPadding)
        buttonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(buttonCount)
        var buttonPosition = CGPointMake(0, padding.height)
        let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width
        for i in 0...(buttonCount - 1)  {
            let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
            button.frame.size = buttonSize
            button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
            buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
            button.setTitle(categoryArr[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button.backgroundColor = buttonColors[i]
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 30
            buttonView.addSubview(button)
            //self.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        }
        buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return buttonView
    }
}
extension ViewController:UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let index = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        print(index)
    }
```

}

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why don't you just set the button image? What does it have to do with the ScrollView? Less code and better description please.

Comment: Sorry, let me be more clear. I don't know how to set the buttons images. I just thought the way you do that might vary because the buttons are in a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the button image or button background image:

```
button.setBackgroundImage(image: UIImage?, forState: UIControlState)
button.setImage(image: UIImage?, forState: UIControlState)
```